# The "currentTime" audio property does not work for my android cell phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom, audio

The "currentTime" audio property does not work for my android cell phone.
When I use the sentence "aud.currentTime=30", this returning to position 0.
Example:

```
<html> 
<body> 

<button onclick="getCurTime()" type="button">Get current time position</button>
<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 30 seconds</button><br> <br><br>
<audio d="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="https://suarezfco65.github.io/amobiodanza/IBFC21 - 18 - OST Metello (Morricone, Ennio) - Metello.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<script>
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
alert("Inicio");

function getCurTime() { 
alert(aud.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() { 
  aud.currentTime=30;
} 
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```